# Blackberry getting notified when the internet connection is available. 

Tags: networking, blackberry, connection, wifi

is there any way to know whether the net is connected or not in a blackbery device .I have the following code but it was waiting till the network timed out.

```
int rc = connection.getResponseCode();
if (rc != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
 throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
}
```

Is there any other way.

Answer (score 4):

The title of this question has a different meaning than the body of the question.  Based on the title, you can be notified when the network starts by using the RadioStatusListener interface, which defines a networkStarted() function.  You could then use the checks that coldice recommends to make sure that the current network supports data transfer.

[RadioStatusListner JavaDocs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioStatusListener.html)

Comment: I def second this, specifically the networkStateChange(int state) method within RadioStatusListner. This will save you the trouble of having a background thread that always checks the network state. 

Though I also recommend checking RadioInfo.isDataServiceOperational() prior to making a data connection each time. Considering that you can get stuck waiting for a timeout, this is a suggested practice.

Answer (score 3):

There are several API for getting network info:

```
RadioInfo.isDataServiceOperational();
CoverageInfo.isOutOfCoverage();
WLANInfo.getWLANState();
```

Comment: +1 RadioInfo.getState() might also be helpful in an effort to create a robust/useful error messages for the users.